# How to turn 2 ints to string in jinja table?

Tags: html, jinja2

I currently have the following problem: I need to display the birthday on a page in the format mm/dd so for example 7/31 for the 31th of July.

I currently have this following code which shows 2 columns, where day and month are seperated:

```
<td>{{ birthday.month }}</td>
<td>{{ birthday.day }}</td>
```

I tried this version:

```
<td>{{ birthday.month / birthday.day }}</td>
```

But then I get the literal mathematic division so 7 / 31 = 0.22 How Can I turn it into 7 / 31 as a string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use two expressions:

```
<td>{{ birthday.month }} / {{ birthday.day }}</td>
```

Consider also to improve the semantics of your HTML by using a [`<time>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time):

```
<td><time datetime="{{ birthday.month }}-{{ birthday.day }}">{{ birthday.month }} / {{ birthday.day }}</time></td>
```